# VB .NET force InternetExplorer to open file inline

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer

is there a way to forse SHDocVw.InternetExplorer to open a file inline instead of asking to download it?
Here is some code:

```
Friend WithEvents browser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
...
browser.Navigate("http://...", , "_self", dataBytes, sHeaders)
```

so it's a POST request

The Response Header includes:

```
Content-Type    application/javascript; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma          no-cache
Content-Disposition attachment
Content-Encoding    gzip
```

iE8 prompts for download (the file has no extension, so only SAVE is allowed) but i'd like to read the response content without any prompts. Is there any way to do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Because I need to navigate trough the site and then execute the POST request. Also I'm not very sure if the site can actually understand that I'm using WebBrowser control or HttpWebRequest in VB instead of a "real" browser.

Comment: If you not need to navigate, you can use the HttpReuqest and HttpRepsonse classes.

Comment: I keep getting "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error." I checked all the header data and it's the same as what I use with iE. Is it possible that the server is not responding to HttpReuqest on purpose?